# download applet failed after changing key on PyApduTool

Tags: javacard, gpshell

Download applet does not work anymore since i changed all 3 default key.

i can authenticate with this script GPShell

```
mode_211 
enable_trace 
establish_context 
card_connect 
select -AID A000000003000000 
open_sc -scp 2 -scpimpl 0x15 -security 1 -keyind 0 -keyver 0 -key a068cd198555af5acc823dfae8a7827a -mac_key a068cd198555af5acc823dfae8a7827a -enc_key a068cd198555af5acc823dfae8a7827a -kek_key a068cd198555af5acc823dfae8a7827a // Open secure channel
card_disconnect 
release_context
```

If i use pyApdutool for download script, i have this error:

```
Download Cap error: Check Card Cryptogram failed.
```

if i change the key GlobalPlatform/Auth and i click to button GP Verify, i have this error:

```
GP Verify error: Check Card Cryptogram failed.
```

Using pyResMan v2.1, if i put my new key on Key Manager and i click to button Mutual Authentication, it work:

```
doMutualAuth(): Start...
doMutualAuth(): Succeeded.
```

I also noticed that since I changed the keys, the version number of the keys has become 2,before, the version was 1.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Buf8g.png)

gp.exe -i -d -v:

```
#
# gp -i -d -v
SCardConnect("Athena ASEDrive IIIe USB 0", T=*) -> T=1, 3BF81300008131FE454A434F5076323431B7
# GlobalPlatformPro 325fe84
# Running on Windows 10 10.0 amd64, Java 1.8.0_261 by Oracle Corporation
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 00A40400 00
A<< (0103+2) (54ms) 6F658408A000000003000000A5599F6501FF9F6E06479100783300734A06072A864886FC6B01600C060A2A864886FC6B02020101630906072A864886FC6B03640B06092A864886FC6B040215650B06092B8510864864020103660C060A2B060104012A026E0102 9000
[DEBUG] GPSession - Auto-detected ISD: A000000003000000
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA9F7F 00
A<< (0045+2) (27ms) 9F7F2A479050354791007833009005024992991894481290120000000006072432343939320000000000000000 9000
[WARN] GPData - Invalid CPLC date: 2432
CPLC: ICFabricator=4790
      ICType=5035
      OperatingSystemID=4791
      OperatingSystemReleaseDate=0078 (2010-03-19)
      OperatingSystemReleaseLevel=3300
      ICFabricationDate=9005 (2019-01-05)
      ICSerialNumber=02499299
      ICBatchIdentifier=1894
      ICModuleFabricator=4812
      ICModulePackagingDate=9012 (2019-01-12)
      ICCManufacturer=0000
      ICEmbeddingDate=0000 (2010-01-01)
      ICPrePersonalizer=0607
      ICPrePersonalizationEquipmentDate=2432 (invalid date format)
      ICPrePersonalizationEquipmentID=34393932
      ICPersonalizer=0000
      ICPersonalizationDate=0000 (2010-01-01)
      ICPersonalizationEquipmentID=00000000

A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA0042 00
A<< (0000+2) (15ms) 6A88
[DEBUG] GPData - GET DATA(IIN): N/A
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA0045 00
A<< (0000+2) (17ms) 6A88
[DEBUG] GPData - GET DATA(CIN): N/A
Card Data:
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA0066 00
A<< (0078+2) (38ms) 664C734A06072A864886FC6B01600C060A2A864886FC6B02020101630906072A864886FC6B03640B06092A864886FC6B040215650B06092B8510864864020103660C060A2B060104012A026E0102 9000
Tag 6: 1.2.840.114283.1
-> Global Platform card
Tag 60: 1.2.840.114283.2.2.1.1
-> GP Version: 2.1.1
Tag 63: 1.2.840.114283.3
Tag 64: 1.2.840.114283.4.2.21
-> GP SCP02 i=15
Tag 65: 1.3.656.840.100.2.1.3
Tag 66: 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.110.1.2
-> JavaCard v2
Card Capabilities:
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA0067 00
A<< (0000+2) (16ms) 6A88
[DEBUG] GPData - GET DATA(Card Capabilities): N/A
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 80CA00E0 00
A<< (0020+2) (21ms) E012C00401028010C00402028010C00403028010 9000
Version:   2 (0x02) ID:   1 (0x01) type: DES3         length:  16
Version:   2 (0x02) ID:   2 (0x02) type: DES3         length:  16
Version:   2 (0x02) ID:   3 (0x03) type: DES3         length:  16

Warning: no keys given, defaulting to 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
SCardDisconnect("Athena ASEDrive IIIe USB 0", true) tx:35/rx:260
```

(My card is not FUSED and not PROTECTED)

I can load, install, select applet, authenticate, on pyResMan, the applet work fine.

But the command gp.exe -l not work.

```
Warning: no keys given, defaulting to 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
Failed to open secure channel: Card cryptogram invalid!
Received: 40FCC922B688B08C
Expected: 327AEEAC380376EC
!!! DO NOT RE-TRY THE SAME COMMAND/KEYS OR YOU MAY BRICK YOUR CARD !!!
Read more from https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalP ... /wiki/Keys
```

What is wrong, if i can authenticate with gpshell script ?

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running gp with `--key a068cd198555af5acc823dfae8a7827a`...

Comment: On a second thought you will probably need to specify all three with `--key-dek`, `--key-enc` and `--key-mac` as otherwise keys would be derived incorrectly.

Comment: And consider to run your working gpshell script after each failed attempt to prevent card blocking (cards typically block after certain number of failed authentications attempts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Given you already resolved your [problem with PyApduTool in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63742902/5128464) by editing the configuration file)

You must specify key value which GlobalPlatformPro should use (otherwise it uses the well-known default key with value `404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F`):

```
java -jar /opt/gp.jar -v -l --key a068cd198555af5acc823dfae8a7827a
```

or alternatively:

```
java -jar /opt/gp.jar -v -l --key-dek a068cd198555af5acc823dfae8a7827a --key-enc a068cd198555af5acc823dfae8a7827a --key-mac a068cd198555af5acc823dfae8a7827a
```

---

Command trace with actual card (gpshell):

> mode_211
> enable_trace
> establish_context
> card_connect
> * reader name Gemalto PC Twin Reader 00 00
> select -AID A000000003000000
> Command --> 00A4040008A000000003000000
> Wrapped command --> 00A4040008A000000003000000
> Response <-- 6F108408A000000003000000A5049F6501099000
> open_sc -scp 2 -scpimpl 0x15 -security 1 -keyind 0 -keyver 0 -key a068cd198555af5acc823dfae8a7827a -mac_key a068cd198555af5acc823dfae8a7827a -enc_key a068cd198555af5acc823dfae8a7827a -kek_key a068cd198555af5acc823dfae8a7827a
> Command --> 8050000008EABF19238386F99C00
> Wrapped command --> 8050000008EABF19238386F99C00
> Response <-- FFFFFFFFFFF71062DA69010200098315C89B44BFA1ED8320EED926819000
> Command --> 8482010010C9F1E010B369F4C0018D22DAC134F1DB
> Wrapped command --> 8482010010C9F1E010B369F4C0018D22DAC134F1DB
> Response <-- 9000
> card_disconnect
> release_context

Command trace with actual card (GlobalPlatformPro):

> [DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Auto-detected ISD: A000000003000000
> [TRACE] GlobalPlatform - Generated host challenge: 292B93656D145F9C
> A>> T=0 (4+0008) 80500000 08 292B93656D145F9C 00
> A<< (0028+2) (35ms) FFFFFFFFFFF71062DA690102000CAF7BB18519650456126907678D0F 9000
> [DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Host challenge: 292B93656D145F9C
> [DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Card challenge: 000CAF7BB1851965
> [DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Card reports SCP02 with key version 1 (0x01)
> [DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Will do SCP02 (8)
> [DEBUG] PlaintextKeys - Card keys: {ENC=type=RAW bytes=A068CD198555AF5ACC823DFAE8A7827A, MAC=type=RAW bytes=A068CD198555AF5ACC823DFAE8A7827A, DEK=type=RAW bytes=A068CD198555AF5ACC823DFAE8A7827A}
> [TRACE] PlaintextKeys - Session keys: {ENC=type=DES3 bytes=FB03954624ADB9A3EC89AE5D2B324D8B kcv=799E36, MAC=type=DES3 bytes=321E2B911ACDCF923C58E93AA44DD7B2 kcv=D7E17A, DEK=type=DES3 bytes=B05E11FF73ECBFB45384446C2E8D5B9F kcv=8DF462}
> [DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Verified card cryptogram: 0456126907678D0F
> [DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Calculated host cryptogram: D4F2E6ABD58F2532
> A>> T=0 (4+0016) 84820100 10 D4F2E6ABD58F253245169D0334285F91
> A<< (0000+2) (18ms) 9000

Comment: Thank you very much vlp, you are resolved my problem. it work fine putting the key after command gp -l