# gp.exe -list return always Cryptogram Failed

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I have changed my defaults keys to A068CD198555AF5ACC823DFAE8A7827A.

but the command from gp -l return always Cryptogral Failed.

note:
I can authenticate with script file on GPShell

I can download applet, install applet and select applet  with pyResMan

I can transmit APDU with pyResMan

I can authenticate with pyResman

GPShell script

```
mode_211 
enable_trace 
establish_context 
card_connect 
select -AID A000000003000000 
open_sc -scp 2 -scpimpl 0x15 -security 1 -keyind 0 -keyver 1 -key A068CD198555AF5ACC823DFAE8A7827A -mac_key A068CD198555AF5ACC823DFAE8A7827A -enc_key A068CD198555AF5ACC823DFAE8A7827A -kek_key A068CD198555AF5ACC823DFAE8A7827A // Open secure channel
card_disconnect 
release_context
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn1YT.png)

I have the same problem withh PyApduTool, i can't download, install applet and authenticate, allways return Cryptogram Failed while with pyResMan all work fine and script GPShell work fine for authenticate.

Can you help me, what is wrong ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please do not post [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63731515/download-applet-failed-after-changing-key-on-pyapdutool).

Comment: For PyApduTool i resolved the problem, it's a bug, 
it is necessary to modify the keys in the config.ini file of PyApduTool.
but i have always the problem with gp.exe -l that return Cryptogram Failed